# How to create a read-only struct without boilerplate code?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

Despite the fact that Rust has absorbed many good modern programming ideas, it looks like one very basic feature is not presented.

The modern (pseudo-)functional code is based on a large number of classes of the following kind:

```
pub struct NamedTuple {
    a: i8,
    b: char,
}
impl NamedTuple {
    fn new(a: i8, b: char) -> NamedTuple {
        NamedTuple { a: a, b: b }
    }
    fn a(&self) -> i8 {
        self.a
    }
    fn b(&self) -> char {
        self.b
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of boilerplate code here. Is there really no way to describe such types compactly, without a boilerplate code?

Comment: Note that you can write `NamedTuple { a, b }`, no need to repeat the name.

Comment: Something like [`getset`](https://github.com/Hoverbear/getset) or [`derive-getters`](https://github.com/kvsari/derive-getters) might be of use here.

Comment: how about making the attributes public and that is all?

Comment: I don't see anything particularly `functional` about this code. This looks more like Java transliterated into Rust. Would you write this kind of code in OCaml or Haskell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have boilerplate, think *macros*:

```
macro_rules! ro {
    (
        pub struct $name:ident {
            $($fname:ident : $ftype:ty),*
        }
    ) => {
        pub struct $name {
            $($fname : $ftype),*
        }

        impl $name {
            fn new($($fname : $ftype),*) -> $name {
                $name { $($fname),* }
            }

            $(fn $fname(&self) -> $ftype {
                self.$fname
            })*
        }
    }
}

ro!(pub struct NamedTuple {
    a: i8,
    b: char
});

fn main() {
    let n = NamedTuple::new(42, 'c');
    println!("{}", n.a());
    println!("{}", n.b());
}
```

This is a basic macro and could be extended to handle specifying visibility as well as attributes / documentation on the struct and the fields.

I'd challenge that you have as much boilerplate as you think you do. For example, you only show `Copy` types. As soon as you add a `String` or a `Vec` to your structs, this will fall apart and you need to either return a reference or take `self`.

---

Editorially, I don't think this is good or idiomatic Rust code. If you have a value type where people need to dig into it, *just make the fields public*:

```
pub struct NamedTuple {
    pub a: i8,
    pub b: char,
}

fn main() {
    let n = NamedTuple { a: 42, b: 'c' };
    println!("{}", n.a);
    println!("{}", n.b);
}
```

Existing Rust features prevent most of the problems that getter methods attempt to solve in the first place.

**Variable binding-based mutability**

```
n.a = 43;
```

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to field `n.a` of immutable binding
```

**The rules of references**

```
struct Something;

impl Something {
    fn value(&self) -> &NamedTuple { /* ... */ }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Something;
    let n = s.value();
    n.a = 43;
}
```

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to field `n.a` of immutable binding
```

If you've transferred ownership of a value type to someone else, *who cares* if they change it?

Note that I'm making a distinction about *value types* as described by [*Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests*](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/toc.html), which they distinguish from *objects*. Objects should not have exposed internals.

Comment: > f you've transferred ownership of a value type to someone else, who cares if they change it? <
Got it. And I'd like to add, as I just discovered, if you want _logically-mutable_ field you should use Cell/RefCell. All fields without Cell/RefCell are _logically-immutable_.

Comment: @warlock I don't agree with that statement. Yes, `Cell` / `RefCell` / `Mutex` / `Atomic*` / etc. are all implementations of *interior mutability* and allow you to mutate something behind an immutable reference, but the opposite doesn't logically extend from this. People **do not** mark fields as `Cell` just to indicate that something is intended to be modified.

Comment: By "logically-mutable" I don't mean just "intended to be modified". I mean, that in situation when in some GC-based language (e. g. C#)  you'd write "readonly" (i. e. immutable) field, in Rust you should use a simple field, and when in C# you'd write mutable field, in Rust you should use (Ref)Cell. It's just two different kinds of mutability, and the first kind _in C#_ is presented as "immutability".

Comment: @warlock I understand your analogy, but I'm saying it's not correct for Rust. *when in C# you'd write a readonly field, in Rust you should use **a plain field**. when in C# you'd write mutable field, in Rust you should use **a plain field***. Mutability is not primarily a property of the type but a property of the binding.

Comment: Lets invert the statement: when in Rust you use plain field, in C# you should use readonly field. I think, you disagree with the original statement, because you disagree with this reverted statement, because you think it does not work. But for people, using modern C#-coding style, it works: they need very serious reasons for introducing a mutable field. I claim, in Rust the same reasons lead to inevitable using of `Cell`. Of course, it is just hypothesis, but I don't see any counterexample for now.

Comment: See also https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/33jv62/vecrcrefcellboxtrait_is_there_a_better_way/cqlm8q1

Comment: @warlock I'm not misunderstanding you, you are just wrong. I'm sorry, but I don't know how to put that any more politely. Different languages have different solutions to problems and attempting to directly map the concept of a `readonly` field to Rust doesn't make sense. Instead, I encourage you to investigate *why* someone would use such a field in C# and then figure out the concrete equivalent in Rust. People do *not* scatter `Cell` and friends throughout their structs to indicate that a field will be updated.

Comment: `Cell` is more like the `mutable` keyword in C++, which is rarely used. You don't use it just so that the member can be changed: you use it so that the member can be changed *even if the object is `const`*. In C++ you'd only use it for things like memoization, so you can cache some values from a `const` member function, and the use cases in Rust are broadly similar. I don't think C# has an equivalent?

Comment: > People do not scatter `Cell` and friends throughout their structs < Ok, they do not, but may be they _should_. In C++ you do not need `mutable` often, because a constant (smart or raw) pointer is not a pointer to constant.

Comment: @warlock no, they *shouldn't*. Interior mutability has to be checked at runtime, while "regular" mutability is checked at compile time. Just... try using Rust they way it's supposed to be used for a while instead of trying to guess. Hopefully that will be able to convey what I am evidently unable to communicate effectively.

Comment: @warlock I can see where you're coming from, but I think you're overlooking the *uniqueness* of `&mut` references, in more than one sense. C#, MATLAB, Python, none of them have an equivalent to `&mut`. C technically has `restrict`, but it's very limited in its capability and rare to find in an API (and it doesn't allow you to modify a `const` member). Whereas practically every Rust API makes *some* use of `&mut`. Which makes sense -- `&mut` references permit mutation, but they also disallow aliasing, which rules out 99% of the kinds of errors you would try to avoid with `readonly` in C#.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Instead of avoiding `mut self` using `RefCell`, I should manually add `mut` mark to functions, which performs `borrow_mut()` operation on struct internals.

Answer (score 5):

Rust doesn't offer a built-in way to generate getters. However, **there are multiple Rust features that can be used to tackle boilerplate code**! The two most important ones for your question:

- **Custom Derives** via `#[derive(...)]` attribute
- Macros by example via `macro_rules!` (see [@Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930642/2408867) on how to use those to solve your problem)

---

I think the best way to avoid boilerplate code like this is to use custom derives. This allows you to add a `#[derive(...)]` attribute to your type and generate these getters at compile time.

There is already a crate that offers exactly this: **[`derive-getters`](https://crates.io/crates/derive-getters)**. It works like this:

```
#[derive(Getters)]
pub struct NamedTuple {
    a: i8,
    b: char,
}
```

There is also [`getset`](https://crates.io/crates/getset), but it has two problems: `getset` should have `derive` in its crate name, but more importantly, it encourages the "getters & setters for everything" anti pattern by offering to also generate setters which don't perform any checks.

---

Finally, you might want to consider rethinking your approach to programming in Rust. Honestly, from my experience, **"getter boilerplate" is hardly a problem**. Sure, sometimes you need to write getters, but not "a large number" of them.

Mutability is also not unidiomatic in Rust. Rust is a multi paradigm language, supporting many styles of programming. Idiomatic Rust uses the most useful paradigm for each situation. Completely avoiding mutation might not be the best way to program in Rust. Furthermore, avoiding mutability is not only achieved by providing getters for your fields -- binding and reference mutability is far more important!

So, use read-only access to fields where it's useful, but not everywhere.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think either crate will return a `T`, they only return a `&T`.